# Is this a unary operation or simply a declaration?

Tags: logic, field-theory

In another question, I was told that I was performing a unary operation by saying:

Let $\Bbb{X}$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{R}$ and closed under division. It follows that:
$$k\in\Bbb{X}\iff\frac{1}{k}\in\Bbb{X}$$

Is this a unary operation of $k$ or simply a logical statement? And if the former is the case, is it $\in$ or $\iff$ that is the operation?

Comment: It is a statement about the "operator" *multiplicative inversion*.

Comment: To say that a structure $\mathbb X$ is *closed with respect to* (unary) operation $\text {Op}$ amounts to saying exactly that: for every $k \in \mathbb X: \text {Op}(k) \in \mathbb X$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, but isn't division always a binary operation?

Comment: @MicahWindsor You can view it as either a binary operation $\operatorname{Div}(1,k)$ or a unary operator $\operatorname{Inv}(k)$.

Comment: In the example above you have considered the "reciprocal" (i.e. multiplicative inverse)... If you want to consider (binary) division, you have to say that: for every $a,b \in \mathbb X : \dfrac a b \in \mathbb X$. I assumed that we were discussing about the "logic"...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, okay. Yeah, I wasn't totally sure if there was enough logic in the post to put that tag on, but there were very few relevant tags and I needed people to see it somehow :/